# using for loop to create html elements

Tags: javascript, html

What is wrong with my code? It is supposed to create input tags in html with using the incoming number (quantity):

```js
// Declare variables
var numberOfGrades = 0;
var NL = "\n";



// Functions
function setQuantity() {
  numberOfGrades = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

  var inputBox = document.createElement("INPUT");
  var BR = document.createElement("br"); // Break line
  var gradeNumber = 1;
  var gradeText = document.createTextNode("Grade " + gradeNumber + ":");

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfGrades; i++) {
    alert(numberOfGrades);
    document.getElementById("formDiv").appendChild(BR);
   document.getElementById("formDiv").appendChild(gradeText);
    document.getElementById("formDiv").appendChild(inputBox);
    gradeNumber++;
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Homework and Quiz average calculator</h1>

  <p>Please Enter the required information to calcuate</p>
  <div class="container" id="formDiv">
    <form id="formID">
      <p>
        <strong>Calculate the average of homework grades</strong>
      </p>
      How many grades?
      <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="10" value="1">
      <!--<input onclick="setQuantity()" type="submit" value="Apply">-->
    </form>
    <button onclick="setQuantity()">APPLY</button>
    <br>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/yrfuwoej/)

Comment: In JSFiddle, click on "Javascript" then change "Load type" to "No wrap - in <body>". Your function isn't available because JSFiddle automatically wraps your code up to avoid creating global variables.

Comment: Right! thanks a lot!

Comment: However, it is still creating only 1 input even if the parameter number is higher than 1. (Meaning, if the user sets the number to 3 and clicks the apply button, the function should create 3 input elements. Now its creating only 1 ignoring the parameter)

Comment: Off topic, but you could cache the value of `getElementById` in a variable. E.g., `var formDiv = document.getElementById("formDiv");` and put it before the loop. Then you're not looking for that element for every grade. It doesn't make much difference speed-wise, but maintainability will be better.

Comment: Check out 6502's answer. You need to create a new element every time you want another element in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks. I moved the variables inside the loop and its good now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `x.appendChild(y)` the node `y` is added as a child from `x` **removing it from where it was if already in the DOM**.

For example:

```
var x = document.createElement("div");
var y = document.createElement("div");
var z = document.createElement("div");
x.appendChild(y);
z.appendChild(y); // now y is not inside x any more, was **moved** to z
```

If you want to have multiple nodes you need to create them inside the loop.